# What is the meaning of "what you have in water" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "what you have in water" in the following sentence,

> Burn something and - whether it's melted or not - you have changed its
>   chemical character, because it become bound to an oxidant (often
>   oxygen -- ooh, what a coincidence!?! -- but not always e.g. you can
>   burn sodium in gaseous chlorine to make salt) and released energy, so
>   you will never get back your starting material without putting back
>   into the system more energy than it gave up in burning.
>
> And that's why we'll never have water-powered cars - you can't burn
>   hydrogen any more than ***what you have in water***. Water is hydrogen ash.

?

source: Mick Wilson's writing in https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-melting-and-burning

Does "You can't burn hydrogen any more than what you have in water" mean "You can't burn hydrogen any more than hydrogen in water" ?

Comment: Can you cite a source for this sentence? It seems incomplete or at least lacking context.

Comment: source:Mick Wilson's writing in https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-melting-and-burning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this means is that when you *completely* oxidize (that is, burn) hydrogen, you have water (H2O). Therefore, you cannot oxidize hydrogen any further than it has been oxidized in water.

Adding in to the sentence you quote:

> you can't burn hydrogen any more **(any further)** than what you have **done to the hydrogen that is in** in water.

Honestly, it's not a very clearly-written sentence. By keeping the vocabulary simple, the author has actually made it difficult to understand.

Comment: Does "what you have done to the hydrogen that is in in water." mean "what you have done(burned) to the hydrogen that is in water" ?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means - the hydrogen in the water is already completely "burned," and it cannot be burned any more.